# In c or c++ can a loop have both "do" and "while" sections?

Tags: c++, c, loops, syntax, do-while

Given the common `while()` statement in both `do ... while` and `while` loops, and the way the place where a `while` loop's body would be replaced with a semicolon on a `do ... while` as if it's a compound statement being turned into an empty statement (or ending the line of a long statement):

Does the syntax in any of the C family languages allow for a "do while and while" loop with both bodies defined?

Presumably the semantics would be a single loop with some operations occurring before the check and some after.

For example:

```
do {
  foo();
} while ( baz() == true ){
  bar();
}
```

`foo()` would always occur once but `bar()` would only occur after if `baz()` returned true.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do

Comment: `in both do and do while loops` What is a do loop?

Comment: Actually, I cannot make heads or tail of this question.

Comment: you want a do-while loop with a block after the condition check? How would that ever execute if the condition is false?

Comment: It wouldn't, like a while loop.

Comment: It's a question about how the syntax tree is constructed, if `while` only appears one place or in two with different meanings.

Comment: I don't understand why this has so many downvotes.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie OP wants a loop where the looping condition could be in the middle,  a kind of looping construct popularized with Ada with its statement `exit when` clause (https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-5-7.html)  which by the way allows for a multi-level exit as well (which is possible in C++ only with a goto  ;-).

Comment: Though really I don't want those semantics.  I'm just asking if the syntax parses, and if so speculating on what the semantics could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In C or C++, Can a loop have both “do” and “while” sections?
>
> Does the syntax in any of the C family languages allow for a "do while and while" loop with both bodies defined?

No, you can either have a while loop or a do-while loop. A while loop is something different than a do-while loop and vice versa.

You can not merge both types together.

---

It can only be a do-while loop:

```
do 
{ 
    /* statements  */ 
}while(condition);
```

or a while loop:

```
while(condition)
{
    /* statements */
};
```

At the while loop, you execute statements *after* a certain condition. At the do while loop  you run at least once through the loop until it reaches the condition. But the center of both loops is at the end the same kind of statements/loop body. Thus, It would make no sense to add a second one.

---

When you use a do-while loop, like the way you have made:

```
do {
  foo();
} while ( baz() == true ){
  bar();
}
```

the area enclosed by `{}` after the do-while loop condition of:

```
{
  bar();
}
```

is not part of the do-while loop.

---

It will be treated as only a bunch of statements in a separate scope block which will get executed *after* the do-while-loop is fulfilled/done.

But even then, the compiler will only let this pass, if you have set the semicolon `;` after the do-while-loop condition:

```
do {
  foo();
} while ( baz() == true );{      // Note the semicolon ";".
  bar();
}
```

With the provided code of:

```
do {
  foo();
} while ( baz() == true ){
  bar();
}
```

the compiler will throw an error.

Comment: So are you saying that you tested this and did not receive compiler errors? I.e. "not part of the do-while, but will be executed". That surprises me. I'd have expected a compile failure for the missing `;`.

Comment: @Yunnosch My thought was that the compiler will treat it as a separate block scope.

Comment: Yes I read your answer that way. I just doubt it. Did you test or not? If you did and report the result I'd believe you. Maybe I'd ask for the exact compiler identification and version you are using...

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, I have tested it. It works that way.

Comment: OK, interesting. So which compiler and version?

Comment: @Yunnosch gcc, 7.4.

Comment: I tried with `gcc (tdm-1) 4.9.2` (coming with of course slighly rusty CodeBlocks 16.01) and it results in `error: expected ';' before '{' token`. Some obvious MRE around it of course. Same with `gcc (tdm-1) 5.1.0` (17.12 CodeBlocks).

Comment: @Yunnosch Did you set the semicolon after the do-while condition?

Comment: I thought we were discussing the code as shown in your answer. More or less `do {/**/} while(0){/**/}`. Were you referring to `do {/**/} while(0);{/**/}`? That would of course match your statement, but it is not the code in your answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch I did not mind, that in the OP´s code was no semicolon. I tested it with a different code. I´ve edited my answer up this way. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, and now I like the answer, nice explanation.

Comment: @Yunnosch My mistake, sorry.Thank you for the tip.

Comment: My pleasure to partake in a constructive discussion. (Actually my respect for making it a constructive one. I now realise that my first comment could have been read in an agressive "voice".)

Comment: I think this means at the parser level `do...while` and `while` are completely different rules which just happen to share the `while(...)` intermediate symbol.

Answer (score 5):

They cannot be used at the same time.  The syntax is either:

> **while** ( *expression* ) *statement*

or:

> **do** *statement* **while** ( *expression* ) ;

So you can't do this as in your example:

```
do {
  foo();
} while ( baz() == true ){
  bar();
}
```

But you can come close with this:

```
do {
  foo();
  if (!baz()) break;
  bar();
} while (1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be asking for

```
do
    statement0
while (condition)
    statement1
```

This can be accomplished with:

```
do
{
    statement0
    if (!(condition)) break;
    statement1
} while (1);
```

Comment: An that's how I'd do this if I actually wanted to do this.  The (apparently hypothetical)  structure I'm talking about would be an obscure seldom used piece of the syntax if it existed.  It would be bad practice to use it.

Comment: I think statement0 in this would be executed one more time than it would in a normal while loop.

Comment: @NO_NAME: Which is what the question appears to request.

Comment: Sorry, I had a do-while loop in mind. Anyway, I was thinking about this some more and my statement is true only if the statement1 is able to change the result of the condition. In that case we need to check the condition a second time at the end of the loop.

Comment: This is actually quite complex. If it is the case that the first statement cannot change the result of the check we need to test it only the first time which may allow some optimization if the condition is expensive enought to compute. Maybe I'm thinking obout it too much, though. The solution with two checks should be fool-proof.

Comment: @NO_NAME: Fool-proof for what? Nothing in the question indicates the OP wants a check at the end of the loop. When I write a regular `do … while` loop, I want a check at the end only. I do not want the loop to jump out at some arbitrary place if the condition happens to be false if it is evaluated there. The question asks for a loop  with the condition evaluated at a certain spot in the middle. That is what this answer provides. You should not be changing the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Both do and while blocks in the same loop are not allowed in C or C++.
It is not allowed in any other programming language as well.

Comment: How do you know it is not allowed in any other programming language?